# How to add a button to a NSMenu that is used as Status bar menu?

Tags: macos, nsmenu, nsstatusbar

I am using following code to create a statusbar menu for my app on MacOS:

```
let statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: -1)

 func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        let menu: NSMenu = NSMenu()
        var menuItem = NSMenuItem()
        menuItem.title = "Hello"
        menu.addItem(menuItem)
      
        statusBarItem.menu=menu
}
```

This works, but I am wondering how to add custom lines to this menu, e.g. containing a checkbox or a button. See the attached screenshot from VLC video player.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy: NSMenuItem has a property view. You can set any view to this.

```
  let menu: NSMenu = NSMenu()
        var menuItem = NSMenuItem()
        
        let frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 20))
        let viewHint = NSView(frame: frame)
        let switchButton = NSSwitch(frame: frame)
        viewHint.addSubview(switchButton)
        
        
        menuItem.view = viewHint
```